# Run external jar inside another jar

Tags: java, scala

It is possible run a jar that I have inside another jar from my class?

I´m trying to run this command from my class

```
java -cp //file:/D:/Users/nb38tv/workspace/f2e-core/f2e-mock/f2e-test-framework/target/f2e-test-framework-1.8.3-SNAPSHOT.jar!/h2/sakila-h2-master/h2-1.3.161.jar -ifExists -tcp -web -tcpAllowOthers
```

But java complain since cannot find the jar.

If I remove the `!` from the path I receive this error

```
Unrecognized option: -ifExists
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to execute a jar embedded in a jar like that, but even if it were possible, your Java command line is simply incorrect. That is because the `-ifExists` (and the other options) are interpreted as commandline options of the `java` executable.

You will get the same error message if you extract that `h2-1.3.161.jar` from the `f2e-test-framework-1.8.3-SNAPSHOT.jar` and tried to execute it with the same command line.

It would either need to use `-jar` instead of `-cp`, or you would need to specify the class to run before `-ifExists`.